# Regex how to get stuff between char without those chars?

Tags: .net, regex

Example:

\Doe, John\" <15553775555>"

The regex is \<(.*?)> and match <15553775555>. But it would be more accurate if it would return only what is inside the < >. How can we modified it to have what's inside? (By the way, what's inside can be not only a 12 digits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a named capturing group :

```
Regex r = new Regex("<(?<number>.*?)>");
Match m = r.Match(input);
if (m.Success)
{
    string number = m.Groups["number"].Value;
    // whatever you need to do with it...
}
```

Or unnamed, if you prefer :

```
Regex r = new Regex("<(.*?)>");
Match m = r.Match(input);
if (m.Success)
{
    string number = m.Groups[1].Value;
    // whatever you need to do with it...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [lookaheads and lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=<)\d+(?=>)
```

Basically what this means is: find a sequence of one or more digits that is preceded by a < and followed by a >. You can of course just do:

```
<(\d+)>
```

because the parentheses mark a capturing group and then you just get that group rather than the entire match. Something like:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<(\\d+)>");
Match match = regex.Match("Doe, John\" <15553775555>");
if (match.Success)
{
  String number = match.Groups[1].Value;
  Console.WriteLine("Found " + number);
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("No match found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab the sub match provided by the parens.  It depends what regex engine you're using as to the syntax, but $1 works in .net I believe...